# Jquery $(this) node and its use

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand some jquery code that uses a `$(this)` node.  What is it used for and when can it be used?

```
$("li").hover(border, noBorder);
function border()
{
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid black");
}
```

Comment: sure are you want us to guess the code?

Comment: can you add some code? `$(this)` in jquery parlance is just `this` wrapped in a jquery object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read [jQuery's this:demystified](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/) by Remy Sharp

> There are really two main contexts of
>   'this' in jQuery. The first refers to
>   a to a DOM element, and the second to
>   a jQuery object.

As a DOM Element

```
$('a.newTarget').each(function () { // <- our anonymous callback
    // check the DOM attribute 'host' on this
    if (this.host != window.location.host) {
        // create a jQuery object using the current DOM element
        $(this).attr('target', '_new');
    }
});
```

As a jQuery Object

```
jQuery.fn.newTarget = function () {
    // 'this' is a jQuery object at this point - with all the jQuery functions

    return this.each(function () { // return so we don't break the chain
        // now we are inside of a jQuery function, the DOM element is the context
        // so 'this' has changed to become a DOM element.

        if (this.host != window.location.host) {
            $(this).attr('target', '_new');
        }
    });
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` just wraps whatever `this` refers to in a jQuery object.  It's commonly used in callbacks to refer to the element that fired the event, amongst other things.

Answer (score 0):

this is used to access the current iterated value on a loop
For example you have a table with 'n' rows ,the following code will alert each row content using this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table#tableid tr').each(function(){

    alert($(this).html());

    }); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use it like this http://jsfiddle.net/HwmEK/7/

Comment: `$(this).doesnt("explain much")`